# One base app for multiple brandings with different views and layouts?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, target

I have built an app that does some computation and communication with varying internet resources. I branded my application with its tab bar navigation bar for three corporate clients, the only change was the difference in pictures and coloring. So I created three targets and handled target membership appropriately.

So far, so good. But what if I wanted to customize the whole layout of views or even the navigation of the app for a client? For example, the next client could ask for a navigation controller based interaction instead of a navigation based on a tab bar. Or to add one more label in one view. Or to use a pie chart instead of a bar graph to visualize a certain set of data.

It leads to very ugly code if you put all different targets in one project with all these if/else if/else if/else if/... blocks of code. What if I had 100 clients?

Now here is the question: In my imagination an ideal concept would be if I could make an Xcode project named "*Base*" that does all the domain specific computations, communications and so on (of course) and has a basic, non-branded UI. This way the code can be easily maintained for all clients in one central repository. Then, for every client, I create a whole new Xcode project, import or reference the "*Base*" project and when I click on Build without any customization, it already builds me the non-branded, but fully functional app. If a client requests to have a modified layout, I subclass the corresponding view. When hitting the Build button again, it should bring up the "*Base*" app but the certain subclassed view replaced the standard layout.

Can this idea of a "*Base*" app with "overriding" the visuals be done elegantly in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly that for a client last year. I had one framework app that used a header shared with the app project. It's almost like a protocol in that the app "commits" to supplying some strings, views, and images. You can start with a fairly simple app project, and as you find you need more variation move code out of the framework into the app. The header was the implementation of a class-methods only class that vended the app specific data.

In my case we had 7 or so apps (all in the store now) yet not a single bit of knowledge in the framework of exactly what app was using it.

As an example in app did launch, the framework might query if a sound should be played and if so ask for that resource - same with images and other variations.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to create a static library.  You could stuff all the commonly used stuff into a [static library](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/) and then reference it in the other projects.

Maybe most of the stuff lives in the static library and you just have one or two files in your app project. This would work well if there a very minimal amount of changes between applications (ie: just style changes like you mention in your post).

Another technique would be to use generated and template code.  The idea would be that you have your boiler-plate code and you run a script that would set up your project and resources based on provided colors, logos, strings, etc.

In the end, you'll likely want to use a combination of the two approaches above based on your requirements.